# Reading 'AutoFilter' data in Excel using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

Using below code (VB.net) i am able to filter Column 'A', 'B' in Excel Sheet. But i am not getting how to read column 'C' filtered data. Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

```
Dim excel_app As New Excel.ApplicationClass()
Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

excel_app = New Excel.ApplicationClass()
excel_app.Visible = True
workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\abc.xls", ReadOnly:=True)
sheet = DirectCast(workbook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
sheet.Activate()
sheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Dim value_range As Excel.Range
value_range = sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
value_range.Select()
'sheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter(Field:=1, Criteria1:="ABC", Operator:=Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues)
'sheet.Range("B1").AutoFilter(Field:=2, Criteria1:="XYZ", Operator:=Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues)
value_range.AutoFilter(Field:=1, Criteria1:="ABC", Operator:=Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues)
value_range.AutoFilter(Field:=2, Criteria1:="XYZ", Operator:=Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues)
```

Comment: What's different about column C? And where's the code to read from it?

Comment: Ted .. Column 'C' having some data similar to Column 'A', 'B'. I didn't write any code to read column 'C' as i am not aware how to read data from filtered area/range.

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue.